# Searching for anaglyph 3D games and apps

Tags: software-recommendation

Hey all, recently I installed the Minecraft .jar and played it. It's a bit of fun, but the coolest thing about it IMO has been the anaglyph 3D option. Yay, a ViewMaster game!
Anyway, I'm looking for other anaglyph 3D games and apps. I understand that there's an anaglyph plugin for Compiz as well, although it apparently is an inactive project since 2008.

An anaglyph interface for Blender would be severely awesome, right?

Comment: Actually, let's open it up a bit- I'm looking for *stereoscopic* games in general, so anaglyph, blue/red, or other filter-type things all are fair game. Feel free to post about shutter glasses too, although hardly anyone has them. Polaroids are out unless someone knows a way to selectively polarize pixels on a computer screen.

Comment: For extra awesomeness, combine with webcam headtracking: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTNG1GN4VV8

Comment: the anaglyph plugin for compiz will make 3D depth between overlapping windows (seeing as there's no point in minimizing/maximizing windows anyway, it's kinda cool to see depth distance between the windows in anaglyph), however it won't make things within a given window 3D. I played around with it back when and found it enjoyable, but I hate to mess around with compiz considering how fragile it is, especially since Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This forum post should help you

http://www.mtbs3d.com/phpBB/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2939&start=0&hilit=linux

Comment: Thanks for the post! Still waiting to hear about anaglyph stuff though...